Footer FPDF Python
By the python code showed below I'd like to add a footer when requested by the user with the setting of the parameter numberpage of the function save_images_as_pdf to on.
In this case I've got a problem: my footer here goes to the top of a new blank page.
Here's my code:
def save_images_as_pdf(image_files, output_pdf, numberpage="off", deformation="off"):
    pdf = FPDF()

    for i, img_file in enumerate(image_files):
        pdf.add_page()
        print(img_file)
        img = cv.imread(img_file)
        img_height, img_width, _ = img.shape
        img_ratio = img_width / img_height
        
        page_width, page_height = 190, 277
        page_ratio = page_width / page_height

        if deformation == "on":
            fit_width, fit_height = page_width, page_height
        else:
            if img_ratio > page_ratio:
                fit_width = page_width
                fit_height = fit_width / img_ratio
            else:
                fit_height = page_height
                fit_width = fit_height * img_ratio
        
        x_offset = (210 - fit_width) / 2
        y_offset = (297 - fit_height) / 2 

        pdf.image(img_file, x_offset, y_offset, fit_width, fit_height)

        if numberpage == "on":
            pdf.set_y(-15)
            pdf.set_font("Arial", "I", 8)
            pdf.cell(0, 10, f'Page {i + 1}', 0, 0, 'C')
    
    pdf.output(output_pdf)
    print(f"PDF has been saved as {output_pdf}")

I have tried to create the footer method, as on the fpdf website, but this don't solve the problem. I think that the issue depends from the image..

I have found the solution of my problem: I have to call the method set_auto_page_break() of the class FPDF with the following instruction:
set_auto_page_break(False, margin = 0.0)

See here for the documentation of set_auto_page_break.
